# RegEx - How to have muliple underscoes in string

Tags: regex

I have a string such as

```
Cantos1#1_Q17070600080_TCR_GD_NORMAL_CONTROL_GD+_06072017173426.pdf
```

my Regex is

```
^Cantos1#\d+_([Q0-9]+)_([A-Z_0-9]+).*\.pdf
```

I need to capture
Q17070600080 and
TCR_GD.
In place of TCR_GD, it can be anything, such as TCR_GD, or MEMB and so on.
Is this possible?

Comment: Will `_NORMAL_` always be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct translation would be

```
^[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+_[^_]+)
```

Use group `1` and `2`, respectively, and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eXm3ID/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are suggesting using underscores as delimiters, and also underscores as delimited values, then no this is not possible, because as you have said "In place of TCR_GD, it can be anything". Regular Expressions (or for that matter, humans reading your string) do not have the ability to discern between these two cases, without prior knowledge of all the delimited values that are possible.